# Typescript. Why described "return value's" type in functional interface is being not strict implemented?

Tags: typescript, interface, typescript-typings

I tried to describe functional interface with specific partial type of return value in one place.

My interface `IStore` contains only one property `test`. If i set my interface to some function `foo`, which return a hashmap also with another properties, typescript tells "all ok". But I need to get ts error while returned value from `foo` is not strict matched with `Partial<IStore>`. Without explicit indication return value on `foo`

```js
interface IStore {test: string;}
type IFunction<S> = (store: S) => Partial<S>;

// no ts errors. WHY?
// that's NO OK for me.
const foo1: IFunction<IStore> = () => ({
  test: '',
  test2: '' // why no errors in this row?
});

// ts error,
// it is working, but not my target case
const foo2: IFunction<IStore> = (): IStore => ({
  test: '',
  test2: '' // error here
});


// Meanwhile...
// no ts error
// that's OK
const foo3: IFunction<IStore> = () => ({
  test: ''
});

// and...
// ts error: Type '{ test2: string; }' has no properties
// in common with type 'Partial<IStore>'
// that's OK
const foo4: IFunction<IStore> = () => ({
  test2: ''
});
```

How can I get error from "case 2" (`foo2`) in "case 1" (`foo1`) without `... (): IStore => ...`?

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/241) in TypeScript.  Excess property checking doesn't occur on function expression returns, although people expect it to.  TypeScript doesn't have a direct way to specify [exact types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936), which is what you want.  There are ways to get similar behavior, but they will likely require you to use a helper function like `const foo = asIFunctionIstore(...)` instead of your desired `const foo: IFunction<IStore> = ...`.  Not sure if you'd be intersted in such a solution

Answer (score 0):

Typescript sometimes apply strict property check, and sometimes doesn't. When colon is applied it always applies strict property check (with the exception of function arguments). When colon isn't applied its comparing the structure to see if matches the structure of the alias, if true the types are compatible and this is the core of structural typing. This colon check applies to the nearest colon in scope.

IStore or Partial when colon is applied to the ReturnType can only have {test: string} or {}; but never excess properties.
I.E

```
const foo2 = (): Partial<IStore> => ({}); // is allowed but...
const foo2 = (): Partial<IStore> => ({notALlowed: true}); // not allowed
```

When colon is not applied it is doing a structural type-check with excess property off this is the case of the type alias for the function.

```
type IFunction<S> = (store: S) => Partial<S>;


const foo1: IFunction<IStore> = () => ({
  test: '',
  test2: '' // why no errors in this row?
});
```

Now there might be some confusion because both snippets implement a colon but the difference lies in where the colon is positioned, in the case of functions, the colon to the left will only apply strict property check on the function arguments but never the ReturnType.